# Set theory Let R a equivalence relation on A and suppose that B is a subset A...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

**Translation:** I'm attempting the following proof, but I don't know which definition to use moving forward; I appreciate the help:

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$, and suppose that $B\subset A$. Prove that, for each $x\in B$, we have $[x]_{R|_B}=[x]_R\cap B$.

Let $x\in[x]_{R|_B}$. Then $(x,x)\in R|_B\implies x\in B\implies x\in A$ by hypothesis, which implies $(x,x)\in R\wedge x\in B$.

---

estoy intentando trabajar en la siguiente demostración pero estoy en este punto y no sé que definición utilizar para avanzar, agradezco las ayudas,

The following picture shows my attempt.
[image]

Comment: Hi Jason Andres. It is good you have shared your attempt, and your handwriting is better than that of many. However, do you think you can typeset your mathematics using our MathJax system? The info is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/688046

Comment: hola Jason, bienvenidos al sitio! :) eres más propenso a recibir una respuesta si preguntas en inglés; puedo traducir su pregunta para ti?

Comment: Hello, i don't know how i use latex language in this program, i need solve this exercise :(

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yes please, help me.

Comment: dígame si hay un error en la traducción :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom It's perfect, thank you so much, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially just a matter of "unwrapping" the definitions; fix $x\in B$. Now, recall that $R|_{B}$ is the intersection of $R$ with $B\times B$, and that $[x]_{R|_B}$ is the set of all $y$ such that $(x,y)\in R|_B$. Thus we have:
\begin{align}
y\in[x]_{R|_B}&\iff (x,y)\in R|_B=R\cap (B\times B) \\
&\iff (x,y)\in R\text{ and }(x,y)\in B\times B \\
&\iff y\in[x]_R\text{ and }y\in B \\
&\iff y\in [x]_R\cap B,
\end{align}
which shows the desired equality.

Comment: R∩(B×B) This "unwrapping" the problem thank you. I will have to study this course, can you recommend me a book where i can see some examples . We use set theory book of Charles C. pinter

Comment: @JasonAndresDiazSuarez de nada, me alegro ayudar :) ... para libros, desgraciadamente no tengo recomendaciones "off the top of my head", pero puedo pensar

Comment: (x,y)∈R|B=R∩(B×B)  ¿cómo logra deducir en la primera parte de la demostración esa igualdad?

Comment: @JasonAndresDiazSuarez ah! esta es la definición de $R|_B$, o por la menos es la definición que conozco. como es la definición para ti? es posible que su profesor tiene una definición diferente

Comment: {( x,y) ∈ R : x,y ∈ B } es la misma ¿ no? me refiero a cómo llega a la igualdad R∩(B×B) . Gracias por escribirme en español.

Comment: hola @JasonAndresDiazSuarez, lo siento para la respuesta tardía, perdí tu mensaje. si, esa es exactamente la misma :) (porque $(x,y)\in R$ con $x,y\in B$ $\iff$ $(x,y)\in R$ y tambien $(x,y)\in B\times B$. tiene sentido?)

Comment: Gracias, me ha quedado claro, podría recomendarme algún libro de teoría de conjuntos con una notación mas sencilla que el de Set theory de Charles Pinter. Necesito mucha mas practica.